# Does using a lower power adapter to prevent fast charging (MBP M1) help preserve the battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I've gone through old well-answered questions about how to prevent a Mac battery lifespan ([Does a low power charger help Macbook's battery](https://superuser.com/questions/1504578/does-a-low-power-charger-help-macbooks-battery), [Limiting macbook (usb c) charge level…](https://superuser.com/questions/1513322/limiting-macbook-usb-c-charge-level-to-60-during-prolonged-desk-usage-by-pl?rq=1), [Apple recommendations](https://www.apple.com/batteries/), etc.), and understood that:

- It's best to stay between 20 % and 80 % (for all lithium-ion batteries)
- It's not a good idea to use a too-low power adapter (drains the battery)
- Fast charging is not great
- Some recommend using [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente-Charge-Limiter) (or just let macOS manage it)

Something I still cannot figure out is if it's a good idea to use a power adapter that is not super powerful to charge slower when the Mac is going to stay wired for several days.

For example, I have a [140W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLYU3AM/A/140w-usb-c-power-adapter) power adapter sold with a MacBook Pro 2021 16' M1 Pro, wired most of the time. When I use it outside I'm happy that the power adapter charges it to 100 % very fast, but when I'm back home and know it'll stay here for several days, I wonder if it might be a good idea to plug it onto a lower power adapter like the [96W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MX0J2AM/A/96w-usb-c-power-adapter) or even the [67W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MKU63AM/A/67w-usb-c-power-adapter) (and leave it to charge and stay at 80-100 % for days on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would need to discern between a theoretical and a  practical "preservation of battery life".

Would using a lower power adapter, which prevents Fast Charging, help preserve the battery? - Theoretically, yes.

In this scenario where the Mac is plugged in for days on end, there would be a very narrow window at the start of your "several days of staying wired" - where for some minutes it fast charges, which slightly increases the temperature of your battery - which ever so slightly decreases the life time of your battery more than not fast charging.

Would using a lower power adapter, which prevents Fast Charging, help preserve the battery? - Practically, not really.

Would it really matter to you if your battery failed to worked to your satisfaction after 4 years, or after 4 years and 2 weeks? - Especially when you factor in the time you have spent worrying about the life time of your battery and implementing various safe guards.

Using free software such as [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente-Charge-Limiter) to limit charging to 80% when staying wired seems like a simple and reasonable thing to do.

Beyond that, I think spending money on a different, lower wattage charger, is simply not practical. The charger would cost you much more than what you save in terms of having to replace the battery slightly earlier.

Comment: Well that's a pragmatic and detailed answer, thanks! I was thinking about it because I'm planning to buy a second power adapter (and would maybe use a 96W for home-charge and the 140W for outside charge).