# Proper way to connect MacBook Pro 16 2023 to a monitor LG 27UL850-W

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi

I used to connect my MBP 2018 to the monitor [LG 27UL850-W](https://www.lg.com/sg/consumer-monitors/lg-27UL850-W). In my old setup, I connected this usb-c port of the monitor to my MBP's usb-c port:

[image]

This connected both the audio/video signal and the power with just one cable! Very cool.

Now, with my MBP 16 2023, this can't be done anymore. So, I connect the monitor's usb-c to the MBP's mag safe 3 (just for the power supply) and I use a separate HDMI cable for the audio/video signal.

Although it seems working, I'm wondering if this setup is safe or if I'd better use the power adapter bundled with the MBP 16 2023 (I do not now if I'm going to miss or break something without it).

Comment: I read the [specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP890?locale=en_US) for the Mac and monitor. I do not understand why you can not use a single cable like you did with the other Mac. The [instructions](https://support.apple.com/guide/macbook-pro/charge-the-battery-apdbc13fd966/mac) for charging the Mac state the USB-C ports can be used to charge the Mac.

Comment: Yes, I tried with the right cable, an all can work in the old way. However, as per the monitor spec, the TB3/ USB-C PD delivers 60W. The bundled power adapter (Mac) delivers 140W. Not sure if it can be a problem as time goes by

Comment: I think it would be 60W from the display regardless if you plug into the MagSafe 3 or the USB-C. You get 140W if you use the 140W USB-C Power Adapter that comes with the Mac. From what I read, 140W is for quick charging. If don't have to quick charge.

Comment: My understanding is with USB-C PD the two devices digitally communicate with each other. They both have to agree before the power is turned on. So the display can only safely charge the Mac or not charging with take place.

Comment: This question is closely related to your question: [Does using a lower power adapter to prevent fast charging (MBP M1) help preserve the battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451389/does-using-a-lower-power-adapter-to-prevent-fast-charging-mbp-m1-help-preserve)

Comment: Thank you @DavidAnderson for the pointer. Even after reading the answer, It isn't still clear to me what is the best setup in my case. I agree on the fact that 60W are the max power delivered from the screen to the MBP. I can't understand if it can be enough (I usually run it plugged-in all the time)

Comment: The best setup in your case would be to charge the Mac by connecting the 140W Power Adaptor that came with the Mac to the MagSafe 3 port. You can still use the USB-C port for the monitor. In this case, I would assume the Mac is not getting any power through the USB-C port.

Comment: Note that both [67W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MKU63AM/A/67w-usb-c-power-adapter) and [96W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MX0J2AM/A/96w-usb-c-power-adapter) USB-C Power Adapters from Apple are not shown to be compatible with your Mac. So most likely the 60W that the monitor can provide would not be enough to charge the Mac while in use. The [140W](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLYU3AM/A/140w-usb-c-power-adapter) USB-C Power Adaptor is shown to be compatible with your Mac.